# I have no Idea why my stoploss is not working?

Tags: pine-script

here's the code

```html
tradeType = input.string(title="Trade Direction", defval="Long", options=["Long", "Short"], confirm=true)
isLong=tradeType=="Long"
sl_long=ta.lowest(low,3)
sl_short=ta.highest(high,3)
strategy.exit("exit",tradeType, limit = isLong?sl_long:sl_short)
```

This should put a stop loss for the lowest price 3 candles before for long and highest price for short

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are doing the exit with the wrong parameter `limit` while you should use `stop`.

Try replacing this line with this:

```
strategy.exit("exit", tradeType, stop = isLong ? sl_long : sl_short)
```